# Go goroutines not beeing executed

Tags: go, goroutine

I am trying to achieve some sort of multi-thread processing over here.

```
func (m *Map) Parse(mapData Node) error {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    for _, node := range mapData.child {
        wg.Add(1)
        go parseChild(node, m, wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    close(errors)
    return nil
}

func parseChild(node Node, m *Map, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    var nodeType uint8
    if err := binary.Read(node.data, binary.LittleEndian, &nodeType); err != nil {
        errors <- err
    }
    if nodeType == OTBMNodeTowns {
        for _, town := range node.child {
            var nodeType uint8

            if err := binary.Read(town.data, binary.LittleEndian, &nodeType); err != nil {
                errors <- err
                return
            }
            if nodeType != OTBMNodeTown {
                errors <- fmt.Errorf("Parsing map towns: expected %v got %v", OTBMNodeTown, nodeType)
                return
            }
            currentTown := Town{}
            if err := binary.Read(town.data, binary.LittleEndian, &currentTown.ID); err != nil {
                errors <- err
                return
            } else if currentTown.Name, err = town.ReadString(); err != nil {
                errors <- err
                return
            } else if currentTown.TemplePosition, err = town.ReadPosition(); err != nil {
                errors <- err
                return
            }
            m.Towns = append(m.Towns, currentTown)
            errors <- fmt.Errorf("This should be called: %v, nodeType)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

But my goroutine never sends anything to the errors channel. Seems to be that the main thread is not waiting for the goroutines to even finish

I have no idea what I am missing here. Im waiting for all routines to finish using wg.Wait but doesnt seem to be working as I think it should

And yes. the slice is populated with atleast 3 results. This is the errrors channel

```
var (
    errors = make(chan error, 0)
)

func init() {
    go errChannel()
}

func errChannel() {
    for {
        select {
        case err := <-errors:
            log.Println(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your `main` function?

Comment: Have you tried printing `nodeType` to see if it's really `OTBMNodeTowns`?

Comment: Yeah removing all the goroutine stuff works fine. Sometimes if I add some stuff like print a string I can see the expected error (if my cpu is fast) I want printed so I assume the main thread is not waiting for the routines. My main function is just a call to Parse

Comment: We can't tell what your main method is from this, but if you are initiating a goroutine to handle all of this, the program can indeed exit before code execution. I remember a trick posted in here by Jim B. about putting a `select{}` statement at the end of main to keep a program alive in these cases. However you'll need to use another channel or lock if you want to allow exit without sending an interrupt.

Comment: For errChannel(), why not just do: `for err := range errors {`

Comment: This kind of issue is usually caused by 1 or 2 miss-called goroutine without proper sync. I've tested with a simplified version of this, and it runs fine: [https://play.golang.org/p/MXdDHsUL66](https://play.golang.org/p/MXdDHsUL66). Perhaps the error comes from the code that you didn't share.